# PHP add_filter with variable?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

This is code in a snippet for Gravity Forms that I've put inside my functions.php.
I guess this is a pretty simple question if I'm able to explain it right.

I got my add_filter calls correct, but they don't pass any variable so my dynamic variables doesn't work. For example when gform_limit_by_field_values executes, $sum_limit will always be the last number in the array. Is there some way to pass the variable in the filter?

```
$sum_form_id_arr = [1, 2];
$sum_field_id_arr = [6, 6];
$sum_limit_arr = [20, 30];

$sum_form_id;
$sum_field_id;
$sum_limit;
$sum_limit_message = 'Sorry, this show is sold out.';
$sum_validation_message = 'You ordered %1$s tickets. There are only %2$s tickets left.';

for ($i=0; $i < count($sum_form_id_arr); $i++) { 
    $sum_form_id = $sum_form_id_arr[$i];
    $sum_field_id = $sum_field_id_arr[$i];
    $sum_limit = $sum_limit_arr[$i];
    add_filter("gform_pre_render_$sum_form_id", 'gform_limit_by_field_values');
    add_filter("gform_validation_$sum_form_id", 'gform_limit_by_field_values_validation');
}

function gform_limit_by_field_values($form) {
    global $sum_field_id, $sum_limit, $sum_limit_message;

    $sum = gform_get_field_values_sum($form['id'], $sum_field_id);
    if($sum >= $sum_limit)
        add_filter('gform_get_form_filter', create_function('', 'return "' . $sum_limit_message . '";'));

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does `add_filter()` do?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 If I get it right it redirects the incoming call, for example "gform_pre_render_1" (which is called from gforms) to my new function "gform_limit_by_field_values".